# PIVOT - SELECT invertendo linha e coluna

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select, pivot

tenho uma tabela assim:

```
codigo  ano  quant
100     2014   15
100     2015   13
100     2016   20
101     2015   15
102     2016   22
102     2014   05
```

quero criar uma query que me liste o código assim:

```
codigo   2014   2015   2016
100        15     13     20
101         0     15      0
102         5      0     22
```

Comment: O que você está querendo fazer é um 'pivot table', e provavelmente vai requerer que o SQL seja montado de forma dinâmica; dê uma olhada nesse [outro post do stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) para algumas formas como isto pode ser implementado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considerando a seguinte estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE anos(codigo     INTEGER,
                  quantidade INTEGER,
                  ano        INTEGER);

INSERT INTO anos(codigo, ano, quantidade)
VALUES(100, 2014, 15),
      (100, 2015, 13),
      (100, 2016, 20),
      (101, 2015, 15),
      (102, 2016, 22),
      (102, 2014, 05);
```

Agrupe os resultados pelo código e realize a condição dentro de um `SUM` para verificar o ano. Caso seja o ano referente a coluna, retorne a quantidade, senão retorne zero:

```
SELECT a.codigo,
       SUM(CASE a.ano WHEN 2014 THEN a.quantidade ELSE 0 END) AS '2014',
       SUM(CASE a.ano WHEN 2015 THEN a.quantidade ELSE 0 END) AS '2015',
       SUM(CASE a.ano WHEN 2016 THEN a.quantidade ELSE 0 END) AS '2016'
FROM anos a
GROUP BY a.codigo;
```

Resultando em:

```
| codigo | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 |
| ------ | ---- | ---- | ---- |
| 100    | 15   | 13   | 20   |
| 101    | 0    | 15   | 0    |
| 102    | 5    | 0    | 22   |
```

---

Veja funcionando no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oeoFqGnFUevwQNs3j9XJv6/0).