# Resultado de query em uma só linha

Tags: mysql, query

Meu banco de dados está assim:

```
id | municipio_id |  ano | populacao
 1 |            0 | 2010 |      5000
 2 |            0 | 2011 |      5000
```

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT
case when ano = 2010 then populacao end a2010,
case when ano = 2011 then populacao end a2011
FROM populacao
where municipio_id = 0
```

O resultado sai assim:

```
a2010 | a2011    
 5000 |  null
 null |  5000
```

Preciso que o resultado saia assim:

```
a2010 | a2011    
 5000 |  5000
```

Como fazer?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [PIVOT - SELECT invertendo linha e coluna](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163386/pivot-select-invertendo-linha-e-coluna)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE
         WHEN ano = 2010 THEN populacao
         ELSE 0
       END) AS a2010,
       SUM(CASE
         WHEN ano = 2011 THEN populacao
         ELSE 0
       END) AS a2011
 FROM populacao
WHERE municipio_id = 0
```

Comment: não deu certo amigo. alterei minha pergunta pra voce ver como está meu banco de dados

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo fiz uma alteração.