# Como posso transformar linhas em colunas?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Abaixo o código SQL estou usando.

```
SELECT
c.id AS colaborador_id,
fc.id, fc.forma_contato, fc.tipo_forma_contato_id
FROM tb_colaboradores AS c
JOIN tb_formas_contato AS fc ON c.pessoa_id = fc.pessoa_id
WHERE c.id = 113;
```

O retorno que estou tendo contém 3 linhas e o campo colaborador_id está duplicado.

```
 colaborador_id |  id   |           forma_contato           | tipo_forma_contato_id 
----------------+-------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------
            113 | 36457 | (83) 27303938                     |                     1
            113 | 36458 | (83) 988484745                    |                     3
            113 | 36459 | leonardocesarrodrigues@img.com.br |                     4
```

Gostaria de obter um retorno assim com os registros tudo em uma única linha:

```
 colaborador_id | telefone_id |    telefone   | celular_id |     celular    |  email_id   |               email               
----------------+-------------+---------------+------------+----------------+-------------+----------------------------------
            113 |    36457    | (83) 27303938 |    36458   | (83) 988484745 |    36459    | leonardocesarrodrigues@img.com.br
```

OBS: Colaborador é um único registro, mas pra cada colaborador pode ter de um a três registros(formas de contato) associados.

Com a ajuda dos colegas abaixo, testei essa instrução SQL, mas os campos forma_contato e contato_id veio {NULL} e os campos tel, cel e email veio vazio.

```
SELECT c.id AS colaborador_id,
array_agg(fc.forma_contato) AS forma_contato,
array_agg(fc.tipo_forma_contato_id) AS contato_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN (fc.tipo_forma_contato_id = 1) THEN forma_contato ELSE NULL END) AS tel,
MAX(CASE WHEN (fc.tipo_forma_contato_id = 3) THEN forma_contato ELSE NULL END) AS cel,
MAX(CASE WHEN (fc.tipo_forma_contato_id = 4) THEN forma_contato ELSE NULL END) AS email
FROM tb_colaboradores AS c LEFT JOIN tb_formas_contato AS fc ON c.id = fc.pessoa_id
WHERE c.id = 113 GROUP BY c.id;
```

Resultado:

```
 colaborador_id | forma_contato | contato_id | tel | cel | email 
----------------+---------------+------------+-----+-----+-------
            113 | {NULL}        | {NULL}     |     |     | 
(0 rows)
```

Comment: e qual é o critério para escolher esse registro? é o primeiro que aparece?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [PIVOT - SELECT invertendo linha e coluna](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163386/pivot-select-invertendo-linha-e-coluna)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tera de usar `MAX` e `CASE` para fazer isso,porem vai precisar de uma coluna de chaves, essa coluna vai servir para determinar em qual coluna deve ser adicionado.

| colaborador_id | id | keys | forma_contato | tipo_forma_contato_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 113 | 36457 | tel | (83) 27303938 | 1 |
| 113 | 36458 | cel | (83) 988484745 | 3 |
| 113 | 36459 | email | leonardocesarrodrigues@img.com.br | 4 |

```sql
SELECT c.id AS colaborador_id,
fc.id, fc.keys, fc.forma_contato,
  MAX(CASE WHEN (key='tel') THEN forma_contato ELSE NULL END) AS tel,
  MAX(CASE WHEN (key='cel') THEN forma_contato ELSE NULL END) AS cel,
  MAX(CASE WHEN (key='email') THEN forma_contato ELSE NULL END) AS email
FROM tb_colaboradores AS c
JOIN tb_formas_contato AS fc ON c.pessoa_id = fc.pessoa_id
WHERE c.id = 113;
GROUP BY colaborador_id
ORDER BY colaborador_id;
```

Dessa forma conseguira fazer o que deseja, do contrário não tem como saber que cada item de `forma_contato` significa.

Exemplo completo com sqlite:

```sql
CREATE TABLE colaborador (
  id integer not null primary key autoincrement,
  created_at datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  nome varchar(255) not null,
  sobrenome varchar(255) not null
);

CREATE TABLE contato (
  id integer not null primary key autoincrement,
  created_at datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  chave varchar(255) not null,
  contato varchar(255) not null,
  colaborador_id intenger not null,
  
  foreign key(colaborador_id) references colaborador(id)
);

insert into colaborador(nome, sobrenome) values('joão', 'silva');
insert into colaborador(nome, sobrenome) values('rui', 'barbosa');

insert into contato(chave, contato, colaborador_id) values('tel', '(00) 3433-3333', 1);
insert into contato(chave, contato, colaborador_id) values('tel', '(00) 3433-3300', 2);

insert into contato(chave, contato, colaborador_id) values('cel', '(00) 99433-3333', 1);
insert into contato(chave, contato, colaborador_id) values('cel', '(00) 99433-3300', 2);

insert into contato(chave, contato, colaborador_id) values('email', 'joao.silva@silva.br', 1);
insert into contato(chave, contato, colaborador_id) values('email', 'rui.barbosa@barbosa.br', 2);

SELECT col.id as colaborador_id,
  col.nome || ' ' || col.sobrenome as nome_completo,
  MAX(CASE WHEN (chave='tel') THEN contato ELSE NULL END) AS tel,
  MAX(CASE WHEN (chave='cel') THEN contato ELSE NULL END) AS cel,
  MAX(CASE WHEN (chave='email') THEN contato ELSE NULL END) AS email
FROM colaborador as col
LEFT JOIN contato as con
ON con.colaborador_id = col.id
GROUP BY col.id;
```

Resultado:

| colaborador_id | nome_completo | tel | cel | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | joão silva | (00) 3433-3333 | (00) 99433-3333 | joao.silva@silva.br |
| 2 | rui barbosa | (00) 3433-3300 | (00) 99433-3300 | rui.barbosa@barbosa.br |

Um exemplo bem esdrúxulo de como usar com `LIKE` para fazer o *pattern match*, porem no PostgreSQL você pode usar o `regex_matches()`. O grande problema de usar `LIKE` é se não estiver bem formatado os dados.

```sql
MAX(CASE WHEN contato LIKE '(__) ____-____' THEN contato ELSE NULL END) AS tel,
MAX(CASE WHEN contato LIKE '(__) 9%' THEN contato ELSE NULL END) AS cel,
MAX(CASE WHEN contato LIKE '%@%.%' THEN contato ELSE NULL END) AS email
```

Comment: Não funcionou, o retorno continua sendo 3 linhas.

Comment: @ZéReisM.Olliver pra mim não funcionou, retornou os campos tudo vazio. Aí eu mudei pra LEFT JOIN ai o campo colaborador_id veio com o id do colaborador, o campo forma_contato e contato_id veio {NULL}, e os campos tel, cel e email veio vazio.

Comment: @RafaelArend adicionei um exemplo completo para você testar.

Comment: Uma terceira meio é usar regex em vez de criar uma coluna para definir o tipo de cada forma de contato dentro do case.

Comment: @ThiagoPrado funcionou muito obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score -1):

Considerando que cada colaborador possui uma linha para cada tipo de contato, segue uma sugestão para testes utilizando um Join (Left) para cada tipo:

```
SELECT
    c.id AS colaborador_id,
    fct.id as telefone_id, 
    fct.forma_contato as telefone,
    fcc.id as celular_id, 
    fcc.forma_contato as celular,
    fce.id as email_id, 
    fce.forma_contato as email
FROM tb_colaboradores AS c
LEFT JOIN tb_formas_contato AS fct
    ON fct.pessoa_id = c.pessoa_id and fct.tipo_forma_contato_id = 1
LEFT JOIN tb_formas_contato AS fcc
    ON fcc.pessoa_id = c.pessoa_id and fcc.tipo_forma_contato_id = 3
LEFT JOIN tb_formas_contato AS fce
    ON fce.pessoa_id = c.pessoa_id and fce.tipo_forma_contato_id = 4
WHERE 
    c.id = 113;
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: muito obrigado sua solução funcionou também.